# I have created dogadapt.html file , when I use method = "post" its showing http error405 . How to fix it?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<style type=" text /css ">
  body{
    background-image:url("https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp9685018.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size :cover;
 }
 input{
    border:1px solid #82b74b;
  
  background-color: #82b74b ;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:300px;
   font-size:22px;
    width:5cm;
    height:2cm;
  border-radius:3px;
color:aliceblue;

 }
 form{
  margin-top:-7cm;
  margin-left:700px;
 }
 div{
  border:1px solid black;
  font-size:25px;
  color:white;
  width:350px;
  height:150px;
  padding:5px;
 margin-left:600px;
  padding-right:10px;
  margin-top:35px;
  font-family: cursive;
  border:none;
 }


</style>
    </head>
    <body>
<div>
To the people out there who buy dogs or cats rather than adopting -
<b>"Dost khareede nhi banaye jaate hai"</b>
</div>
  <form action="dog1.html" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Started Now">  
 </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

When I click on  'Get Started Now' I  actually  need navigate to dog1.html file , but instead  I am getting http error 405.

1. - The problem is not  only with this file ,   wherever  If I start  using  this post method facing the same issue in other files tooo.

   ---

Comment: Why are you trying to make a POST request to an HTML file in the first place?

Comment: Have you looked up what [that status code means](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=http+405&t=fpas&ia=about)? Why do you expect your HTTP server to output anything other than a 405 for an HTML file?

Comment: Actually I tried with get method its working ,but when i used post i showing error,why that so same issues in other flies tooo

Comment: What are you trying to do with your post? Remember HTML is not a scripting language, so there's nothing to interpret the data you're POSTing, (or GETting, for that matter). From your example, it looks like your form is essentially just a hyperlink to another page. At that point, why not just use an `<a>`?

Comment: @Vaishnavi — It isn’t surprising that GET works. It isn’t surprising (to me) that POST doesn’t work. Why do you think POST should work? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

@Vaishnavi The action attribute submits information to the server and is processed in the back end code which is handled by php or another programming language the front end code is just directing the destination.

So without something configured and set up to receive and read the information the 405 error message will display.

Hope that helps